# Issue in Checkbox

Tags: html, css, razor

Hai I have a code below

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Status <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<div class="can-toggle">
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsActive)
<label for="IsActive">
<div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="InActive" data-unchecked="Active"></div>
 </label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i will send "IsActive" always true from controller so label will be active
but when i toggle label still "IsActive" will be true[image]

Comment: If `m.IsActive` is set to true.When the checkbox is checked,it will pass true,or it will pass nothing to action.

Comment: when i toggle the label to inactive or active (left or right) isActive remains the same(true) . this is my issue am facing